# What is a good way to sort an array by attribute that is not naturally ordered in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
array = [{ name:'Joe', class:'foo' },
         { name:'Bob', class:'bar' },
         { name:'Hal', class:'baz' },
         { name:'Kim', class:'qux' },
         { name:'Zoe', class:'bar' }
        ]
```

What is a good way to sort by class in the following order: qux, bar, foo, baz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order = %w[qux bar foo baz]
array.sort_by{|h| order.index(h[:class])}
```

gives:

```
[
  {
    :name  => "Kim",
    :class => "qux"
  },
  {
    :name  => "Bob",
    :class => "bar"
  },
  {
    :name  => "Zoe",
    :class => "bar"
  },
  {
    :name  => "Joe",
    :class => "foo"
  },
  {
    :name  => "Hal",
    :class => "baz"
  }
]
```

Comment: @BSeven: I would have been faster if I didn't spend precious seconds trying to pretty format the output (which I included from the beginning) :)

Answer (score 3):

Like this, for example:

```
array = [{ name:'Joe', class:'foo' },
         { name:'Bob', class:'bar' },
         { name:'Hal', class:'baz' },
         { name:'Kim', class:'qux' },
         { name:'Zoe', class:'bar' }
        ]

order = %w[qux bar foo baz]

sorted = array.sort_by{|el| order.index(el[:class])}

sorted # => [{:name=>"Kim", :class=>"qux"}, 
       #     {:name=>"Bob", :class=>"bar"}, 
       #     {:name=>"Zoe", :class=>"bar"}, 
       #     {:name=>"Joe", :class=>"foo"}, 
       #     {:name=>"Hal", :class=>"baz"}]
```